# How to test if UIActivityTypePostToFacebook or UIActivityTypePostToTwitter is available

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift2

I'm working on an app where a user can unlock some features if they share through social media. Under normal circumstances when a user is signed into Facebook or Twitter, then the Facebook and Twitter activities are displayed when the user hits the share button. However, I want to handle the case where the user isn't signed into Facebook or Twitter. I just don't know how to test if they are signed in. I assume there's a way to do it without having to explicitly install the Facebook SDK as iOS can handle facebook log in natively.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've worked it out.

```
SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter)
```

and

```
SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook)
```

are the two methods that can be used to check if the user is signed into the respective social network.